# Methods in making sure a python script always runs even if it exits in error

Tags: python

I am new to Python and have a project that is time-sensitive and also a prototype that I need to make sure it runs no matter what errors pop up. I have built a python script that works and works with some inputs that sometimes loses connection which results in my script exiting with an error. I'd like to find a simple but effective way in making sure that if my script is exited that it can be automatically executed again.

I have read that I could create another python script that uses subprocess.Popen() to call the python script I have developed but not sure if this is the best method or how it would be utilized in code in executing the script if it errors.

Can anyone outline what the best way to go about doing this? I know that being able to handle each error would be best but there can be numerous reasons why the script exits and it works if I just run the script again since I initialize everything in the beginning.

Comment: Read up on exception handling so that disconnections or poor inputs don't cause your script to die.

Comment: Python has [many mechanisms for handling errors gracefully](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) without immediately exiting. See `try ... except ... finally` for the most frequently-used mechanism, and the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) for another that is often useful. Beyond that, your question is a bit too vague to give any specific advice. Please show some of your code and the errors that result from it.

Comment: Thanks Dan, your comment with just supplying try except and finally has gotten me in the right section of my books to be able to start to understand this concept. I have coded a long time ago and know basics but I will admit that the question is vague but not knowing the python terminology makes it hard to pinpoint where I should be looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easier solution that you can do within your existing script.

Let's say your existing top-level code looks like this:

```
def main(args):
    # etc.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

You can change it to do this:

```
def safe_main(args):
    try:
        main(args)
    except BaseException as e:
        print("I'm logging an exception and restarting: {!r}".format(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    while True:
        safe_main(sys.argv)
```

---

This doesn't work in *every* case. If it's possible that your script will actually segfault (e.g., because you're calling an unstable C exception), or that some other process will kill it, and you want it to restart even in those cases, then you need an external wrapper. But for most cases, neither of those comes up.

But even in that case, there are often easier, and more robust, options than writing a wrapper script. For example, there's a good chance you want this to run as a Unix daemon, Mac LaunchAgent, Windows service, etc. If so, there are libraries that wrap up the appropriate behavior for you, and then you can use your platform's built-in service-managing code to relaunch the program if it ever exits.

Comment: This question is far to broad to answer. The asker clearly has no clue about error handling, so they will likely copy and paste the code directly in and not understand why it works, or more likely, why it doesn't.

Comment: I agree that the question is too broad for an adequate answer, but I'd say this is a useful response by @abarnert in terms of illustrating the basic mechanism of error handling, which is likely what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: I tried to write it so that the code would be easy to use if you understand it, hard to use if you don't. (For example, someone who has no clue what he's doing, and no inclination to learn, probably doesn't have a `main` function like that…) Do you really think this is feeding a vampire instead of helping a novice?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: And also, I think this answer covers most reasonable cases, and explains the edge cases it doesn't cover, which implies that it's not necessarily too broad to answer. Of course if the OP comes back with "I don't get it, write me the codez", then I'll concede.

Comment: I appreciate your response and answer in this. I have enough to work to know what path to take. I have the books but I don't have time to read every chapter and get an overall understanding... I wish I could but I don't... You also can't just copy paste code because in most cases it will causes errors and I need to understand it so now I can focus on what I need to understand.

Comment: @DeucePie: Just trying to write code, and using the places you get stuck or the code you don't understand as pointers to what to read up on next, is a _great_ way to learn programming, or a new language; definitely don't apologize for that! But if you're going to use StackOverflow as a guide when you get stuck, you really need to read the Help section here, or you're going to get a lot of downvotes, closes, and (worst of all) bad answers.